# How to fix rioxarray.exceptions.DimensionMissingCoordinateError: x missing coordinates?

Tags: netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

I'm trying to reproject a NetCDF file without an assigned projection. I was successful in assigning projection. But, while attempting to reproject the file, I receive the following error: `rioxarray.exceptions.DimensionMissingCoordinateError: x missing coordinates.` I looked at the x variable in the xarray dataset and I'm not able to see any missing values. Further, I think my Xarray dataset stores the coordinates in `longitude` and `latitude` fields and not as `x` or `y`. How can I tell Rioxarray to use correct longitude and latitude fields. I'm unable to find the way to change it in the doc [here](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_dataset.RasterDataset.reproject)

```
import xarray

path_file = './2002_01_01_T_03_00_to_2002_01_02_T_09_00.nc' 
xds = xarray.open_dataset(path_file)

# Assign crs to the data
xds.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)

# Reproject
xds3857 = xds.rio.reproject("EPSG:3857", nodata=0)
```

An example NetCDF file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/t/uaxl6XHpgYevp3Ie)

A view of data:
[image]

Comment: I also tried `xds.rio.set_spatial_dims('longitude', 'latitude', inplace=True)` with no success. The error now is `rioxarray.exceptions.MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension (longitude) not found.`

Comment: The x/y coordinates need to be 1 dimensional. Have you verified how many dimensions your coordinates are?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually associated with two circumstances.

1. You haven't told xarray what is the x/y dim so you should do

```
import xarray

path_file = './2002_01_01_T_03_00_to_2002_01_02_T_09_00.nc' 
xds = xarray.open_dataset(path_file)

# Assign crs to the data
xds.squeeze().transpose('lat', 'lon').rio.\
   set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon",y_dim="lat").\
   rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

# Reproject
xds3857 = xds.rio.reproject("EPSG:3857", nodata=0)
```

2. However, if you still confronted with same error using new `reproject_match()`. It might be your DataArray `xds` wasn't given a DataArray's varibalename. However, if you get the varible through calculation of couples of other DataArrays, it will defaultly name it '**xarray_dataarray_variable**'. So your code can be modified as follow:

```
import xarray

# Reproject
xds3857 = xds.nameofthevariable.rio.reproject("EPSG:3857", nodata=0)

# if it's calculated variable
xds3857 = xds.__xarray_dataarray_variable__.rio.reproject("EPSG:3857", nodata=0)
```